# String concatenation inside angular brackets in HTML

Tags: python, html, string, jinja2, string-concatenation

How do I concatenate strings inside jinja brackets {{ }} in HTML?

Ex: `<img src="{{ image.file.name }}">`

I need to concatenate with the image.file.name.

ex: `<img src="{{ 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/images/' + image.file.name }}">`

But his didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should write like this

```
<img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/images/{{ image.file.name }}">
```

in jija you don't have to concat with `+` it will replace {{}} without it

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm.

Comment: can you accept my edit? about adding jinja2 tag in your question